# How can I copy files from a Google Cloud Compute engine(linux terminal) to google cloud shell?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to transfer files stored in the google compute engine linux terminal to the google cloud shell. Is there a command line to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that from Cloud Shell. use the `scp` command (ssh cp)

```
gcloud compute scp <instance name>:<file or dir to get> <destintation> --zone <Zone of the instance>
```

Of course, the port 22 must be open to internet (firewall rule with 0.0.0.0/0 on port 22) and you must have the required permission to log into the VM

---

**EDIT 1**

You can perform the same operation from your environment with gcloud CLI. The command is this one

```
gcloud cloud-shell scp localhost:<Local files> cloudshell:<Cloud shell dir>
```

Comment: And what would be the command for transferring files from cloud shell to google cloud vm?

Comment: Switch the source and the destination, as a usual `cp` command! `gcloud compute scp <local sources> <instance destination name>:<dir to put files> `

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the compute engine also? Can I use the same command?

Comment: In the edit you have given localhost. How to change it to transfer files from google compute vm to google cloud shell? Also how to activate google cloud shell from google compute vm? Is there a command? I am using linux environment

Comment: The localhost, is the current environment on which you are running the command. If you are on the VM, it's your VM. If it's your computer, it's your computer.

Comment: Ok what about activating the google cloud shell from the google compute vm?

Comment: And also when I tried the command mentioned above for transferring files between cloud  shell and google vm I was getting permission denied, even though I have enabled the required permissions.